# firestore cloud functions for getting aggregated values in collection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

lets say I have a app that stores users bills, user adds or deletes the bill. the structure of the data is as:

```
users/user_id/bills/bill_id
```

bill document structure as

```
{ bill_name: string, amount: number }
```

what I want to show the user aggregated values corresponding to bill name
lets say I have 2 entries in bills collection

```
{ bill_name: 'amazon', amount: 1000 }
{ bill_name: 'amazon', amount: 2000 }
```

my output should be

```
{ bill_name: 'amazon', amount: 3000 }
```

my question is what will be best to get the aggregated values

1. Create a cloud function that triggers on **onWrite** `/user/user_id/bills/bill_id`
   and create a new entry in `/users/user_id/aggregated_bills/` at the time user adds or deletes the bills and what this function does read the data from `/users/user_id/aggregated_bills/bill_id/` where bill name is 'amazon' add do the math to this entry and store the new value in aggregated_bills collection.
   also I want to know if we can add or read the database from cloud function other then it was referenced. in `functions.firestore.document('/users/{user_id}/bills/{bill_id}').onWrite( ...`
2. create a cloud function that triggers on HTTPS request, and read the data from `/users/user_id/bills/` where bill name is 'amazon' and calculate the aggregated values there, and return the response.
3. may be any other solution for this problem

> here I want to say that getting aggregated values will be not only for
>   one bill, but for multiple bills at the same time. lets say I want to
>   show the user dashboard where he is seeing aggregated values of his
>   top 20 bills

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onWrite` trigger would make the most sense in this situation. Consider writing the aggregate results as an object/map on the parent document because then you will only need one read operation to consume the data - faster and cheaper.

Your cloud function would look something like this:

```js
exports.aggregateBills = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{user_id}/bills/{bill_id}')
    .onWrite(event => {

    const bill_id = event.params.bill_id; 
    const user_id = event.params.user_id;

    const bill_name = event.data.data().bill_name;

    // ref to the parent document
    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId)

    // get all bills and aggregate
    return docRef.collection('bills')
         .where('bill_name', '==', bill_name)
         .get()
         .then(querySnapshot => {
            // get the total comment count

            const bills = []
            // loop over bills to create a plain JS array
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                bills.push( doc.data() )
            });

            const aggregateData = 'do your calculations here'


            // run update
            return docRef.update({ aggregateData })
         })
});
```

Comment: +1 on this, writing aggregated data is quite common in NoSQL solutions and Cloud Functions are a great tool for doing such operations. An alternative is to do the aggregation client-side (as you add the bills), but that requires some quite tricky security rules to ensure malicious users can't perform invalid writes. Since Cloud Functions run in a trusted environment, you won't have to worry about somebody writing their own aggregation code that violates your business rules.